# Eclipse - Creating custom "run"

Tags: java, python, eclipse

i have got a question about the run menu of Eclipse.

My problem:
I'm programming a plugin which can only be started when I type some commands in my command line (e.i. Preparing all files, creating a jar file, coping it in a specific path) and pressing a key in a program. I cannot run it as an normal java application.
So, I have written a python script which does it for me. (I chose python as a script language because it is cross-plattform. I could do it in java but the JVM needs too much time to start).
That way (switching to the command-line, pressing the arrow key, pressing enter) needs too much time, however. It would like to press only the run button in eclipse as I am used to with other Java Application.

What I also want to have:
I want only to press the run button in eclipse to start that python script. The output of the console should be the output of the python script. The run should be terminated as soon as the python script ends running.

I am not going to programme a "Eclipse Plugin", which does it. I only want a way which needs at most 5 minutes to configure my "Run Script".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: panel screenshot]
Find this little icon on your panel. There you can add and configure any external scripts to run